# Column space of matrix A=LU subspace of C(L)?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix that is factorized as $A=LU$, show that the column space of $A$ is a subspace of the column space of $L$, where $L$ has $1$'s on the diagonal.

I just have issues showing that a linear combination is the subset of another linear combination.

Thanks

Comment: Does $L$ imply "unit lower triangular"?  If so, then $\det(L)=1$, and $L$ is invertible, so the column space of $L$ is $K^n$ (where $K$ is the underlying field).  Thus, the column space of any $n \times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\mathrm{col}(L)=K^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  You have to show that every vector in ${\rm col}(A)$ is also in ${\rm col}(L)$.  Now the elements of ${\rm col}(A)$ consist of $A$ times any vector, and likewise the elements of ${\rm col}(L)$ consist of $L$ times any vector.  So, if you have an element $A{\bf x}$ and you know that $A=LU$, can you see how to write
$$A{\bf x}=L({\rm some\ vector})\ ?$$